# How do I check for Invalid Binary Inputs

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm having a problem checking for invalid binary inputs from the user. Here is the program. Can anyone tell me how to approach this?

These are the errors I'm getting

1. error C2660: 'binToDec' : function does not take 1 arguments
2. warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
3. error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'bin'
4. error C2275: 'std::string' : illegal use of this type as an
   expression. see declaration of 'std::string'
5. error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'bin'

   ```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<string>
   #include<math.h>

   using namespace std;

   void intro();
   bool isBinary(string);
   void decToBin();
   string getBin();
   void binToDec();
   char getChoice();
   char getContinue();

   int main()
   {
       char choice, cont;
       string bin;

       intro();

       do{
           choice = getChoice();
               if(choice == 'b' || choice == 'B')
               {
                   bin = getBin();
                   bool binIsBinary = isBinary(bin);
                   if(binIsBinary)
                       binToDec(bin);
                   else
                   {
                       cout<<"Error!!! Your Number is Not Binary"<<endl;
                       cout<<endl;
                   }
               }

               if(choice == 'd' || choice == 'B')
                   decToBin();
           cont = getContinue();
         }
       while(cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y');
   }



   void intro()
   { 
       cout << "This program coverts decimal numbers to binary and vice versa.
                << endl;
   }

   bool isBinary( string bin )
   {
      int i=0;
      bool binIsBinary = true;

      while (i < bin.length())
      {
         if( bin.at(i) != '1' && bin.at(i) != '0' )
             {
             binIsBinary = false;
             }
             i++;
      }

      return binIsBinary;
   }

   void decToBin()
   {
      int dec;
      string bin;

      cout << endl << "Please enter a decimal number:"; 
      cin  >>  dec;
      bin = "";

      while (dec != 0)
      {
         if (dec % 2 == 0)
            bin.insert(0, "0");
         else
            bin.insert(0, "1");
         dec = dec / 2;
      }
      cout << "The equivalent binary number is: " << bin << endl << endl;

   }

   string getBin(string bin)
   {   
       string bin;

       cout << endl << "Enter a binary number: ";
       cin  >>  bin;

       return string;
   }

   void binToDec(string bin)
   {
       double deci;
       string bin;
       double len;

      len = bin.length();

      deci = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
          if (bin.at(i) == '1')
              deci = deci + pow(2, len-i-1);

      cout << "The equivalent decimal number is: " << deci << endl    
           << endl;
   }

   char getChoice()
   {
       char choice;

       cout << endl << "If you would like to convert a binary to a decimal then enter b."<<endl; 
       cout << "If you would like to convert a decimal to a binary then enter d. ";
       cin >> choice;

       return choice;
   }

   char getContinue()
   {
       char cont;

       cout << "Would you like to convert another number(Y/N)? ";

       cin >> cont;

       return cont;
   }
   ```

Comment: `void binToDec();` The compiler's just following what you told it on that one.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what your comment. I thought if I put bin = getBin() then I could use the function calling with bintoDec()

Comment: look at your second test on `choice`, you're testing for 'd' or **'B'**.

Comment: change `string getBin(string bin)` definition (down the file) to the same at your declaration (at the top of the file), the parameter isn't necessary.

Comment: My point is that it's `void binToDec();` in the declaration and `void binToDec(string bin)` in the definition. The compiler has only seen the former when you call it with an argument.

Comment: thanks for that diderc, I just caught my mistake before I saw this comment.

Comment: in `isBinary` you compare `i` with `bin.length()`, which have different "signeness". i should be of type `size_t`.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean now chris. Thanks for the headsup. After editing a bit, I;ve gotten it down to 2 errors. warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'bin'

Comment: Okay, I fixed the error with the formal parameter. Another careless mistake. Now I'm trying to fix the signed/unsigned mismatch error. I still have question about the function getBin() as I'm trying to set the return type as a string. Does this work? Also, I'm confused on what you mean when you say i should be of size_t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've corrected the problems in your code, though didn't check if the decimal to binary and binary to decimal conversion is correct or not. Problems were mainly because of your wrong function definition and wrongly passed parameters in the functions. Here is the modified code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

void intro();
bool isBinary(string);
void decToBin();
string getBin();
void binToDec(string);
char getChoice();
char getContinue();

int main()
{
    char choice, cont;
    string bin;

    intro();

    do{
        choice = getChoice();
            if(choice == 'b' || choice == 'B')
            {
                bin = getBin();
                bool binIsBinary = isBinary(bin);
                if(binIsBinary)
                    binToDec(bin);
                else
                {
                    cout<<"Error!!! Your Number is Not Binary"<<endl;
                    cout<<endl;
                }
            }

            if(choice == 'd' || choice == 'B')
                decToBin();
        cont = getContinue();
      }
    while(cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y');
}



void intro()
{ 
    cout << "This program coverts decimal numbers to binary and vice versa." << endl;
}

bool isBinary( string bin )
{
   int i=0;
   bool binIsBinary = true;

   while (i < bin.length())
   {
      if( bin.at(i) != '1' && bin.at(i) != '0' )
          {
          binIsBinary = false;
          }
          i++;
   }

   return binIsBinary;
}

void decToBin()
{
   int dec;
   string bin;

   cout << endl << "Please enter a decimal number:"; 
   cin  >>  dec;
   bin = "";

   while (dec != 0)
   {
      if (dec % 2 == 0)
         bin.insert(0, "0");
      else
         bin.insert(0, "1");
      dec = dec / 2;
   }
   cout << "The equivalent binary number is: " << bin << endl << endl;

}

string getBin()
{   
    string bin;

    cout << endl << "Enter a binary number: ";
    cin  >>  bin;

    return bin;
}

void binToDec(string bin)
{
    double deci;
    double len;

   len = bin.length();

   deci = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
       if (bin.at(i) == '1')
           deci = deci + pow(2, len-i-1);

   cout << "The equivalent decimal number is: " << deci << endl    
        << endl;
}

char getChoice()
{
    char choice;

    cout << endl << "If you would like to convert a binary to a decimal then enter b."<<endl; 
    cout << "If you would like to convert a decimal to a binary then enter d. ";
    cin >> choice;

    return choice;
}

char getContinue()
{
    char cont;

    cout << "Would you like to convert another number(Y/N)? ";

    cin >> cont;

    return cont;
}
```